# Как вывести в массиве объекты?

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Как вывести все объекты массива $arrs. Через foreach. Как вывести $arr или $arr2 я знаю, а вот с массива как вывестих все.

```
$arrs = array();
$arr = new stdClass();
    $arr->name = "Andrii";
    $arr->age = "25";
    $arr->long = "1.85";
    $arr->male = "man";
$arr2 = new stdClass();
    $arr2->name = "One";
    $arr2->age = "23";
    $arr2->long = "1.70";
    $arr2->male = "man";

$arrs[] = $arr;
$arrs[] = $arr2;
```

Разобрался. Нужно было просто 2 foreach

```
foreach ($arrs as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
       echo $key1." => ".$value1;
    }
}
```

Comment: что вы имеете в виду под понятием вывести объекты массива?

Comment: У меня в массиве $arrs два объекта $arr и $arr2. Как их вывести в цикле с массива $arrs ?

Answer (score 3):

Вывести все поля объекта можно, например, так:

```
$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->foo = 'bar';
$obj->baz = 'quux';

foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $key => $value) {
    echo($key . ' => ' . $value . "\n");
}
```

Выведет:

```
foo => bar
baz => quux
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](https://3v4l.org/M5Mhe) на 3v4l.org.

Для итерации по массиву объектов можно использовать еще один (внешний) цикл `foreach`.

Comment: Это вывод из объекта. А у меня объекты в массиве. Я знаю, что можно вывести так:  Или так и нужно выводить с массива  объекты.                                                                           foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
 echo $key.'' -> ". $value;
}

Comment: Добавьте внешний `foreach` для массива и будет вам "счастье" :)